# Add/Remove class to get a menu to display

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I started programming the mobile version of my nav menu earlier. I had to rework my `#serviceNav` to get it to work in a mobile setting. When doing this I changed my javascript from this:

```
/*$('#serviceClick').click( function () {
      $('#serviceNav').addClass('activeSol');
});*/
$('[data-pop-close]').on('click', function(e)  {
    //var targeted_pop = $(this).attr('data-pop-close');
    $('#serviceNav').removeClass('active');
    $('body').css('overflow', 'auto');
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

To this:

```
$('#serviceClick').click(function() {
    var relative = $(this);
    if (!relative.hasClass('activeSol')) {

$('.activeSol').removeClass('activeSol').next('#serviceNav').slideUp(500);
        relative.addClass('activeSol').next('#serviceNav').slideDown();
        //$('.infoTitles:before').addClass('opened');
    } else {
        relative.removeClass('activeSol').next('#serviceNav').slideUp(500);
    }
    return false;
});
```

The issue that I am having now that I previously didn't with my javascript code is that now my desktop media query version of my `#serviceNav` is not displaying, however it does display and function in the mobile setting. The trigger for this menu is the menu item called "Solutions". You can see that in a media query over 640px that nothing happens, but 640px or less it applies the `fadeDown` function.

Does anyone see why this is not working for the larger version media query?

[Here is a jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ftp91gyn/2/)

Full code:

```js
$('#mobile-button').on('click', function () {
  $('#nav-pop').addClass('active');
  $('html').addClass('is-navOpen');
 });
  /*$('#serviceClick').click( function () {
        $('#serviceNav').addClass('activeSol');
 });*/
$('#serviceClick').click(function() {
  var relative = $(this);
  if (!relative.hasClass('activeSol')) {
   $('.activeSol').removeClass('activeSol').next('#serviceNav').slideUp(500);
   relative.addClass('activeSol').next('#serviceNav').slideDown();
  } else {
   relative.removeClass('activeSol').next('#serviceNav').slideUp(500);
  }
  return false;
 });
```

```css
nav {
 background: #FFF;
 height: 70px;
 width: 100%;
 max-width: 100%;
 box-shadow: 0px 6px 15px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 z-index: 999;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
#nav-logo {
 float: left;
 height: 100%;
 width: auto;
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 margin-left: 5%;
}
#nav-logo img {
 height: 80%;
 width: auto;
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 transform: translateY(-50%);-webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
}
#mobile-button {
 background-image: url("https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/mbkitsystems/menu.svg");
    background-size: 30px 30px;
 float: right;
 width: 30px;
 height: 30px;
 margin-right: 5%;
 margin-top: 15px;
 cursor: pointer;
 display: none;
 transition: ease 0.3s;-webkit-transition: ease 0.3s;
}
#mobile-button:hover {
 transition: ease 0.3s;-webkit-transition: ease 0.3s;
}
#nav-pop {
 float: right;
 display: block;
 margin-right: 5%;
 margin-top: 25px;
 transition: ease 0.5s;-webkit-transition: ease 0.5s;
}
#nav-pop.active {
 opacity: 1;
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
 background: #2f2f2f;
 right: 0;
 margin-top: 0;
 margin-right: 0;
 z-index: 999999;
 transition: ease 0.6s;-webkit-transition: ease 0.6s;
 transform: translateX(0);-webkit-transform: translateX(0);
 box-shadow: -9px 0px 9px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}
#nav-list li {
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 0 17px;
 vertical-align: top;
}
#nav-list li:first-child {
 margin-left: 0px;
}
#nav-list li:last-child {
 margin-right: 0px;
}
#nav-list li a, #serviceClick {
 text-decoration: none;
 font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
 font-size: .9rem;
 color: #747678;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
 vertical-align: top;
 transition: all .3s;-webkit-transition: all .3s;
 cursor: pointer;
}
#nav-list li a:after, #serviceClick:after {
 content: '';
    display: block;
 width: 0;
 margin-top: 6px;
 background: #b82222;
 height: 2px;
 transition: width .3s;
}
#nav-list li a:hover, #serviceClick:hover {
 color: #4b4b4b;
 transition: all .3s;-webkit-transition: all .3s;
}
#nav-list li a:hover:after, #serviceClick:hover:after {
    width: 100%;
    transition: width .3s;
}
#nav-list li a.navInverse {
 padding: 10px 12px;
 border-radius: 2px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
 font-size: 1.2rem;
 color: #FFF;
 border: 1px solid #b82222;
 background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, #b82222, #a51e1e);
 text-transform: uppercase;
 text-decoration: none;
 cursor: pointer;
}
#nav-list li a.navInverse:hover {
 background: #b82222;
 background: #FFF;
 color: #b82222;
 /*transition: all 0s;-webkit-transition: all 0s;*/
}
#nav-list li a.navInverse:after {
 content: '';
    display: none;
 width: 0px;
 height: 0px;
 transition: none;
}
#nav-pop-close {
 display: none;
}
#nav-pop-close, #close-panel {
 position: relative;
 top: 3%;
 left: 90%;
 background-image: url("https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/mbkitsystems/icon_close.png");
 background-size: 30px 30px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
 height: 30px;
 width: 30px;
 cursor: pointer;
}
/*- Service NAV -*/
#serviceNav {
    width: 100%;
    top: -40vh;
 left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    height: 40vh;
    transition: all .4s;
 padding: 20px 0;
}
#serviceNav.activeSol {
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.9);
    z-index: 99999;
 height: 40vh;
}
.popup-close {
 position: absolute;
 right: 12px;
 top: 12px;
 width: 32px;
 height: auto;
}
#serviceNavInner {
 margin: 0 5%;
 height: 100%;
 position: relative;
}
/*--- Block 1 ---*/
#serviceNavBlock1 {
 width: 33%;
 height: 100%;
 border-right: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.5);
 position: relative;
}
#serviceNavBlock1Wrap {
 width: 80%; 
 text-align: left;
}
/*--- Block 2 ---*/
#serviceNavBlock2 {
 width: 66.6%;
 height: 100%;
 margin: 10px auto;
 position: relative;
}
.servNavItemWrap {
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
 width: 25%;
 margin-bottom: 50px;
 text-align: center;
 cursor: pointer;
 -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.servNavItemWrap img {
 width: 75px;
 height: 75px;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.25s;transition: all 0.25s;
}
.servNavItemWrap:hover img {
 -webkit-transition: all 0.25s;transition: all 0.25s;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);transform: scale(1.1);
 -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.servNavItemWrap a {
 text-decoration: none;
 outline: none;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
.servNavItemTitle {
 margin-top: 5px;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.25s;transition: all 0.25s;
}
.servNavItemWrap:hover .servNavItemTitle {
 color: #FFF;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.25s;transition: all 0.25s;
}

/*---------------------------------------------- MEDIA QUERY 640 --------------------------------------------*/

@media screen and (max-width:640px) {
  
  #mobile-button {
 display: block;
}
#nav-pop {
 float: none;
 opacity: 0;
 position: fixed;
 margin-top: 0;
 width: 75%;
 right: -100%;
 height: 100vh;
 transform: translateX(100%);-webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
}
#nav-pop-close {
 display: block;
 background-size: 20px 20px;
 height: 20px;
 width: 20px;
}
#nav-list {
 margin-top: 20px;
}
#nav-list li {
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 20px 10%;
 background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #151515, #2f2f2f);
 background: #2f2f2f;
 text-align: left;
 cursor: pointer;
 border-bottom: .3px solid #FFF;
}
#quoteButton {
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
}
#nav-list li:hover #quoteButton {
 background: #2f2f2f;
}
#nav-list li:hover, #nav-list li:active {
 background: #000;
}
#nav-list li:first-child {
 margin-left: 0;
}
#nav-list li:last-child {
 margin: 20px auto;
 text-align: center;
 border-bottom: none;
 background: #2f2f2f;
 padding: 20px 0;
}
#nav-list li a, #serviceClick {
 font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
 font-size: .8rem;
 color: #FFF;
 letter-spacing: .3rem;
}
#nav-list li a:after, #serviceClick:after {
    display: none;
}
#nav-list li a:hover, #serviceClick:hover {
 color: #FFF;
}
#nav-list li a:hover:after, #serviceClick:hover:after {
    width: 0%;
}
/*- Service NAV -*/
#serviceNav {
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    height: 200px;
    transition: all .4s;
 padding: 10px 0;
 display: none;
 top: 0;
}
#serviceNav.activeSol {
    background-color: #000;
    z-index: 9999999;
 height: auto;
 min-height: 20%;
 top: 0;
 border-bottom: .01em solid #FFF;
}
.popup-close {
 display: none;
}
#serviceNavInner {
 margin: 0 2.5%;
}
/*--- Block 1 ---*/
#serviceNavBlock1 {
 width: 100%;
 height: 50px;
 border-right: none;
 display: block;
 position: relative;
}
#serviceNavBlock1Wrap {
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
}
#navOverviewT, #navOverviewP {
 display: none;
}
#solOverviewB {
 font-size: .7rem;
}
/*--- Block 2 ---*/
#serviceNavBlock2 { 
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 margin: 10px auto;
 display: block;
}
.servNavItemWrap {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 25%;
 margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.servNavItemWrap img {
 width: 30px;
 height: 30px;
}
.servNavItemTitle {
 margin-top: 5px;
 font-size: .5rem;
}

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
 <div id="nav-logo">
 </div>
 <div id="mobile-button"><img src="" class="hidden" alt=""></div>
 <div id="nav-pop">
 <div id="nav-pop-close"></div>
  <ul id="nav-list">
   <li><a href="http://localhost:8080/about.php">ABOUT</a></li>
   <li id="serviceClick">SOLUTIONS</li>
   <div id="serviceNav">
    <div id="serviceNavInner">
     <div id="serviceNavBlock1" class="iblock">
       <a href="http://localhost:8080/solutions.php"><button class="buttonInv2" id="solOverviewB">Solutions Overview</button></a>
     </div><div id="serviceNavBlock2" class="iblock">
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <li><a href="http://localhost:8080/learn.php">LEARN</a></li>
   <li><a href="http://localhost:8080/contact.php">CONTACT</a></li>
   <li><a href="http://localhost:8080/quote.php" class="navInverse" id="quoteButton">REQUEST QUOTE</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot going on here and frankly, it's hard to decipher but I think "Nothing happens" is relative. When inspecting the element in dev console you can see the Javascript styling is being added appropriately. So something is happening, it's simply happening off screen because you've told it to. I think the culprit here, is the >640px positioning of your `#serviceNav` element is maintained at `top: -40vh;` That's a lot. When removing this value the button displays as follows:

[image]

Note: you will have to change some other things around as this displays it on page load. But you get the idea

Comment: ah, I see that it's -40vh because the serviceNav-inner height is set to 40vh.